# InsufficientExecutionStackException

Tags: .net, exception, clr

Has anyone ever encountered the `InsufficientExecutionStackException`? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.insufficientexecutionstackexception.aspx) doesn't tell much about it.

What is the difference between the `InsufficientExecutionStackException` and the `StackOverflowException`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This exception is thrown by `RuntimeHelpers.EnsureSufficientExecutionStack`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.ensuresufficientexecutionstack.aspx

In contrast to a `StackOverflowException` you can catch a `InsufficientExecutionStackException` and handle the situation gracefully.

Answer (score 2):

From [CLR Via C#](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/csharp/9780735640467/exceptions-and-state-management/debugging_exceptions#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODA3MzU2NDA0NjcvNTA0)

> Just before invoking a method, you
>   could check for ample stack space by
>   calling the RuntimeHelper class’s
>   EnsureSufficientExecutionStack method
>   This method checks if the calling
>   thread has enough stack space
>   available to execute the average
>   method (which is not well defned)  If
>   there is insuffcient stack space, the
>   method  throws an
>   InsufficientExecutionStackException
>   which you can catch  The 
>   EnsureSufficientExecutionStack method
>   takes no arguments and returns void 
>   This method is typically used by
>   recursive methods